# How do you require variables without a prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have a file with some helper functions to be used in two other files. I want to import the functions, but the way I'm used to doing this is not ideal:

```
helper = require('./helpers')
helper.log()
helper.ok()
...
```

I'd like to be able to use the functions without the `helper` prefix (e.g. `ok()`). How can I do this?

**Edit:** There are currently 7 helper functions, and that number may grow in the future, so specifying each function by hand seems like it defeats the purpose of using a separate file.

Comment: Why the down-votes? I get the feeling people don't think I should be doing this, but nobody's saying why.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Seeing as nobody has yet offered a solution that doesn't involve specifying each function you want to import, here's a solution that is perhaps not ideal, but works:

```
const helpers = require("./lib")
for (let k in helpers) {
    eval(`var ${k} = helpers.${k}`)
}
```

Comment: This does not work under "use strict" before. May be a useful idea anyway (in very special cases)

Answer (score 7):

You could use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const {log, ok} = require('./helpers');
log();
ok();
```

Answer (score 6):

Unlike ES2015, Python or other languages, you cannot export a specific function from another file and use it directly. What you can do in ES5 is to:

```
helper = require('./helpers')
var ok = helper.ok;

ok(...);
...
```

Or if you prefer oneliners:

```
var ok = require('./helpers').ok
```

That is I presume you are exporting a single object of the various functions you have in `helpers.js`.

Whereas in ES2015, you have to write it slightly differently.

First, your `helpers.js` needs to export the functions separately like this:

```
export function ok(args) {
  ...
}

export function log(args) {
  ...
}
```

Then in your main script:

```
import {ok, log} from './helpers';
ok(...);
log(...);
```

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import

Comment: About the first part of your answer, a shorter version exist: `var ok = require('./helpers').ok`

Comment: @DrakaSAN: feel free to edit the answer (: That is correct!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `node -r ./myfunctions.js` (where the argument has to be an absolute path or to start with `./`), or you can run `.load myfunctions.js` in the REPL:

```
$ cat myfunctions.js
p=console.log
$ node -r ./myfunctions.js
Welcome to Node.js v18.3.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> p(5)
5
undefined
>
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v18.3.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> .load myfunctions.js
p=console.log

[Function: log]
> p(5)
5
undefined
$ alias node='node -r ~/myfunctions.js'
$ echo 'p(5)'>script.js
$ node script.js
5
```